# Display multiple images on one window in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, subplot

These are my original images which I need to display in one figure,

[image]

The following is my source code,

```
function draw_multiple_images(image_list)    
    N = length(image_list);
    [m, n] = factor_out(N);

    % create the subplots
    figure;

    if(iscell(image_list))    
        for k=1:N
            h = subplot(m,n,k);
            image(image_list{k},'Parent',h);
            set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick',[])
        end    
    elseif(isvector(image_list))
         for k=1:N
            h = subplot(m,n,k);
            image(image_list(k),'Parent',h);
            set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick',[])
        end
    end
end
```

**Output**

Why do I see them as blue-yellow?

[image]

**I need to show them as black-white.**

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Image_list is the list of the names of the images?

Comment: Or is the image as matrix?

Comment: What I want to know is how you read the pictures.

Comment: try with: `image(uint8(image_list(k)),'Parent',h);` please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by using `colormap(gray(256));`   just after the `figure` command.

```
function draw_multiple_images(image_list)    
    d = size(image_list);
    l = length(d);

    figure;
    hold all
    colormap(gray(256));  

    if(l==2)
        N = length(image_list);
        [m, n] = factor_out(N);

        if(iscell(image_list))    
            for k=1:N
                h = subplot(m,n,k);
                image(image_list{k},'Parent',h);
                set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick',[])
            end    
        elseif(isvector(image_list))
            for k=1:N
                h = subplot(m,n,k);
                image(image_list(k),'Parent',h);
                set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick',[])
            end
        end
    elseif(l==3)
        N = d(3) ;
        [m, n] = factor_out(N);
        for k=1:N
            I = image_list(:,:,k);
            subplot(m,n,k);
            imshow(I);
            set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick',[])
        end  
    end     
    hold off
end
```